# streaming videos from home linux server

Tags: streaming

At home I have a large nas with a bunch of video files on it (various filetypes).  I'm looking for a way to stream those videos if I need them so I can watch them from any computer that has a internet connection.

It would need username/password protection or at least ip based protection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) + firewall

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a VPN connection, allowing you to just directly connect to the server across the internet. A good package download will get you started...

```
sudo aptitude install pptpd
```